# TFS and MSTest discard files created used during testing

Tags: tfs, mstest, tfsbuild

In some tests I create some temporary files. When these are run during the TFS build process they are stored in the TFS database which is bloating it unnecessarily. Where can I put these files so they don't get stored with the test results.

Currently I am using TestContext.TestResultsDirectory. Is there another folder that we can use that will be ignored?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just store them in c:\temp? Or clean them up when you are done...

Comment: - Storing in c:\temp. They are used as part of a build process, multiple builds can be running at once, file names could clash. Would like to know if there is an actual temp directory that can be used in a test context.

Comment: then use c:\temp\$(buildnumber)\